# NativeScript 5 - iOS Out of memory crash and memory leaks

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, angular7, nativescript-angular

Copy here: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6607

**Stack:**

- tns 5
- angular 7

**Demo repository:**

https://github.com/reposooo/ns-out-of-memory

based on similar issue in ns3: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4490

**Steps to reproduce (the same results with AOT):**

> tns run ios

[should open app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcmud.png)

- open memory report in Xcode
- click to example loop 2-4 times
- click to loop 10x

[Reserved memory hasnt gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilays.png)

Comment: Have you confirmed that `ngOnInit` is only ever called once? It looks to me like it should be called every time you show that screen again, which creates more and more subscribers, each of which is referencing `this` strongly instead of using `WeakRef`.

Comment: Its already answers in the issue above. - https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6607

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the report. We have responded in the GitHub issue and the problem is fixed and will be released with {N} iOS Runtime version 5.0.1.